# MySQL Prevent Double Inserts

Tags: mysql, insert, locking

I'm keeping daily logs in a MySQL table. My app tries to UPDATE the row in the table where the date column is equal to today; if the UPDATE doesn't affect any rows, the app knows that a row hasn't been made for today yet, so it then inserts one instead.

I'm trying to prevent the case where two different threads end up inserting a row for today. Is there any way to do this (i.e. with some type of locking) that would be an alternative to setting a unique index on the date column?

I've looked at threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025839/mysql-unique-index-used-as-exception-handling-method-in-java), but I'm not so sure it would work - will wrapping this in a transaction prevent another thread from also inserting this row? I'm assuming I would really need an isolation level that would prevent phantom inserts, like serializable, for this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've done some more research. It seems that InnoDB transactions operate, by default, in the REPEATABLE READ isolation level, which uses [next-key locks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html), which should [prevent the phantom insert problem](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-next-key-locking.html). So, I believe that just by wrapping this in a transaction this issue should be avoided automatically in InnoDB... can anyone confirm this for me?

EDIT - I see that if the UPDATE was instead a SELECT, we'd have to use a [shared mode lock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html). Since this is an UPDATE, should it still work without any extra settings?

EDIT2 - In order to have next-key locking work for this scenario, the date column would need an index, correct?